# Why do I see 100% CPU spikes when looking at htop?

Tags: top, htop

Occasionally, when looking at htop, I'll see my CPU spiking to 100%.

However, when I sort my running processes by CPU utilization, they don't sum to 100%. They don't even come close.

What "hidden" processes are running that are consuming my CPU?  Can I see them?

Note that I'm still finding this to be the case, even though I modified htop's settings to display all threads and to not hide kernel threads.

Comment: You'll have more luck asking this on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

For example IO wait (time CPU used to wait disk and other IO devices) is not counted on process CPU percents. In case of virtual machine, stolen processor time (used by host or another virtual machine) is not showing up on process CPU times either.

Also, typically sum and per process values are not perfectly in sync.